# jQuery mobile, trigger <select> to open when another element is clicked

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I have a list of options (not actual tags, just elements to click on), for example:

- A
- B
- C

If I click `A` for eg., I want it to automatically open a `select` interface (using `jQuery` if possible) so the user will pick a choice (to actually open it to view the options inside it, so the options won't be hidden).

I use Phonegap too, maybe it can help.

NOTE: This is only for mobile devices, not desktops.

Comment: I am usually giving comments like this, when I can't understand the OP's intentions, but here, you just have to read. I want to force the `<select>` to show it's options, by clicking another element. Edit: I see that you deleted your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this way:-

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/WjaVk/)**

### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>A
        <select id="list">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

### JS:

```
$('li').one('touchstart', function() {
    $('li #list').show();
});
```

**OR**

```
$('li').one('touchstart click', function() {
    $('#list', this).show();
});
```

Basically you should use `touchstart` as the event.

Comment: If you use .one() the event handler gets unbound directly after the first execution. With .on() it persists.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a solution. Since I use jQuery mobile, sorry that I didn't mention that, it's pretty important, It wraps the select inside some divs. Here's the fiddle that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/9txeC/